# How to preserve a cell values as text in CSV report generated using xquery and emailed using xdmp:email

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am generating a report in CSV format in XQuery and mailing it using `xdmp:email`. Some of the cell values in the CSV report are displayed as formula (`1.92E+11`) so I had to download the report and format it every time.

Is there any way to retain text values as such in the CSV reports?

Here is sample the of XQuery code

```
xdmp:email(
      <em:Message
       xmlns:em="URN:ietf:params:email-xml:"
       xmlns:rf="URN:ietf:params:rfc822:">
        <rf:subject>{fn:concat($emailSubject,' Generated ',' on ', $dateTime )} </rf:subject>
        <rf:from>
          <em:Address>
            <em:name>{$fromName}</em:name>
            <em:adrs>{$fromAddress}</em:adrs>
          </em:Address>
        </rf:from>
        <rf:to>
          <em:Address>
                <em:adrs>{$to}</em:adrs>
              </em:Address>
          </rf:to>             
        <rf:content-type>multipart/mixed; boundary={$boundary}</rf:content-type>          
         <em:content xml:space="preserve">{$content}</em:content>
      </em:Message>)
```

Comment: So how does `$content` look exactly? Where do you bind a value to it?

Comment: this is how $content looks like
let $rows := for $order in $doc/order 
                        return fn:concat("'",fn:string-join(($order/productID/text(),xs:string($order/orderID/text()),$order/quantity/text()),"','"),"'") || "&#x0A;"

let $generatedReport := ($header,$rows)
let $newline := "&#13;&#10;"
let $boundary := concat("boundary-", xdmp:random())
let $content := concat("--",$boundary,$newline,"Content-Type: text/csv", $newline,"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TestReport.csv", $newline,$newline,document{ $generatedReport }, $newline)

Comment: If you provide additional information, you can do that in a more readable manner by using the `edit` link https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60831738/edit below your question. So which values are shown using exponential form `1.92E+11`, the quantity ones? Have you tried to use `format-number` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-format-number to ensure you get the wanted format? Not sure whether Marklogic supports it but probably they provide some way to format numbers.